# Analytical solution for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$ u _{xx} + u =   -1 $

How would i work out the 'general ' solution to this ode|?

my book says the answer is $ u(x) = a sin(x) + b cox(x) = -1 $

where

$  a = \frac{1-cos(1)}{sin(1)} $

$  b = 1$

I am not sure how to get this, can anyone suggest show me  a method? thank you

Comment: Plenty of methods are known for solving an ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients like $f''+f=-1$. You should just open the book at the right page.

Comment: Notice that $u(x)$ cannot be at the same time $a\sin x+b\cos x$ and $-1$, so there must be some copy&paste issue in your question body.

Comment: it must be $$u(x)=a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)-1$$ shurely a typo

Comment: Look on the web with keyword "harmonic oscillator": you will get thousand of hits, for example this site (http://physics.info/sho/).

Comment: is this correct,? I still cant get the a and b $ u = e^{mx} $ $ m^{2} e^{mx} + e^{mx} +1$   $ m^{2} = \sqrt{-1] $

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let $v(x) = u(x) + 1$.  The ODE becomes:
$$
v'' + v = 0.
$$
This is the simple harmonic oscillator equation.  To see why it has the suggested solution form, convert it to a 1st-order 2-dimensional system: let $v_{1} = v$, and $v_{2} = v' = v_{1}'$.  We then have:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{l}
v_{1}\\
v_{2}\\
\end{array}\right]' = 
\left[\begin{array}{l}
v_{2}\\
-v_{1}\\
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0\\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{l}
v_{1}\\
v_{2}\\
\end{array}\right].
$$
Now find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the square matrix, and you will see the form of the solution.

The $a$ and $b$ will be determined by the initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto avs's solution,

If you let $v=u+1$, you get $v''+v=0$

The characteristic equation of the ODE in $v$ is $r^2+1=0$.

Therefore, $v=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)$.

Rewriting in terms of $u$ gives us $\boxed{u=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)-1}$

Comment: how do i know the values of and b as it states in the answer?

Comment: This is explained in the last line of my answer.